# How to add an object without a constructor to a list using Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring-el, spring-expression-language, spring-expression

I want to add a `BigDecimal` to a list using Spring Expression Language.

```java
public class SpelTest {

    public List<BigDecimal> values;
    
    StandardEvaluationContext context;
    SpelExpressionParser parser;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        values = new ArrayList<>();
        context = new StandardEvaluationContext(this);
        parser = new SpelExpressionParser(new SpelParserConfiguration(true, true));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldChangeValue() {
        values.add(BigDecimal.ONE);

        parser.parseExpression("values[0]").setValue(context, "123.4");

        assertThat(values.get(0)).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(123.4)); // passes
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAddValue() {
        parser.parseExpression("values[0]").setValue(context, "123.4");

        assertThat(values.get(0)).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(123.4)); // fails
    }
}
```

Changing the first entry passes but adding an entry fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.math.BigDecimal.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer$CollectionIndexingValueRef.growCollectionIfNecessary(Indexer.java:715)
    ... 55 more
```

Not sure why SpEL isn't able to properly initialize a `BigDecimal` when the list is empty. Surprisingly I found nothing about this problem.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please find some explanation (no solution, though) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28498439/3890673)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid this problem by setting the whole list instead of single (not initialized) elements. Instead of

```
parser.parseExpression("values[0]").setValue(context, "123.4");
```

use:

```
parser.parseExpression("values").setValue(context, "123.4");
```

This also works for multiple elements, quite neat:

```
parser.parseExpression("values").setValue(context, "123.4, 456.7");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you activated `autoGrowCollections` on the `SpelParserConfiguraion`.
Therefore it tries to create an element with a default constructor if you try to access a non-existing element of the collection with the index operator `[]`. `BigDecimal` has no default constructor and because of this, it fails.

What you could do is to create the object in the SpEL itself. E.G.:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldAddValue() {
        parser.parseExpression("values.add(0, new java.math.BigDecimal(\"123.4\"))").getValue(context);

        assertThat(values.size() > 0);
        assertThat(values.get(0)).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(123.4)); 
    }
```

Or you could create a subclass of `BigDecimal` witch has a default constructor and use this class.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nirud pointed out, the problem is, that `BigDecimal` does not have a default constructor. I extended SpEL to add `null` to the list, when there is no default constructor. See this pull request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/25367